# IIS 7.5 "The specified application pool does not exist"

Tags: iis-7.5

At the moment I have a problem with my IIS. I cannot create an application pool anymore.

Here are the steps I do to create my application pool:

I go into IIS, click on "Application Pools", right-click, "Add Application Pool...", I enter the name of my application pool and then press OK, the following message shows up "The specified application pool does not exist."

Under the application pool list, the name of my newly "created" pool appears with a red cross on it, with status "unknown".

On the left side of IIS (where "Application Pools" & "Sites" are located), if I click on "Sites" then go back to "Application Pools" the pool doesn't show up anymore. But if I close IIS and then come back, it's back again.

However I cannot add a website to the application pool even though I can select it when I click "Select..." trying to add a Web Site.

I followed the recommendation on this page to uninstall completely IIS and the WAS service, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8436cdf3-0d96-45b2-bf2e-8e5ca02342c8/windows-process-activation-service?forum=winservergen. But the problem persists.

At this point I don't know what to do.